# Share a folder between Google Drive, Dropbox and Skydrive

Tags: windows-8, dropbox, google-drive, onedrive

I use three different systems to synchronize my files to the cloud. Google Drive is for my Android tablet, Skydrive for my Windows 8 phone and Windows RT tablet and Dropbox for things at work. This works fine, but on my main desktop at home, these three come together on a single system. Here I have a folder called "Shared" and below three folders, each for every virtual drive. Which is logical, since each system handles completely different data. I have eBooks for my Android tablet, pictures from my phone and projects from work all nicely separated. Works like a charm!
Except, I have a few files that I want to be available on all three systems. Files that are updated regularly on my home desktop. (Read only by my other devices.) And right now, to share with all, I need to copy them twice. This is *not okay*...
What's the simplest (and cheapest) way to make sure I can share a single folder between these three cloud drives, without having to share everything?

Comment: Be aware: the share is needed on just a single system! No remote sharing, because I use those cloud drives for remote sharing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a folder in one of those, and then symlink it form others (For God's sake, backup whatever you place there). On windows [LinkShellExtension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) is godsend.

Comment: Lifehacker did this at http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder so +1

Comment: LinkShellExtension did the trick! And very nicely too, I might add...